# How do i import this to phmyadmin wherein the rows are seperated by table?

Tags: database, csv, phpmyadmin

csv dataset that I am having trouble with importing.
Example data column names:

```
Name   |   Role   |   Room.Code   |   Room.Instructor   |   Subjects.Status   |
```

Is it possible to import this .csv file where in any column name with `.` for example: `Room.Code`  will be imported in a separate table called `Room`? with the column name `Code` and `Instructor`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no unfortunately you will have to standardize this CSV before importing it

Comment: alright, thank you for.

Answer (score 0):

Python is the answer.

With pymysql and numpy, you could.

Use numpy.genfromtxt() to convert CSV to a numpy array. From there, split the table using python code, and have it base it on the name of the column.

This code would probably take maybe an hour or so to make, so if the dataset is really big, it might be worth it.

After you get the seperated numpy arrays, use pymysql to put them into phpmyadmin(like you are using currently).